# How to generate a subgraph with selected nodes and edges together?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph of 100 nodes and 750+ edges among them.

I want to select 30 nodes (union of a set of 15 nodes and another set of 20 nodes), the edges among these 30 nodes.

Is there a possibility of selecting both nodes and edges simultaneously?

Comment: Try `induced_subgraph(g, union(v1,v2))`, where `v1` and `v2` are two sets of nodes?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thanks. I want to select the edges too. I want to retain the edges only from `v1` to `v2`, not within `v1` or `v2`.

Comment: Could you share your data using `dput()` as well as expected output?

Comment: If you look up the documentation of the `induced_subgrph` function which @ThomasIsCoding suggested, you will see that there is also a `subgraph.edges` function which takes edges as input. If your graph has no isolated vertices, this will do what you want. You only really need this function if you want to retain attributes, otherwise you might as well construct the graph from scratch, since you know which edges you want already.

Comment: @Szabolcs I want to retain the edge attributes. My network also contains isolated vertices and I wish to retain them. However, I could use `subgraph.edges` for one of my other use cases, thanks.

Comment: @Prradep Then instead of keeping edges you want, delete edges (and vertices) you don't want.